# magento static block images disappear intermittently

Tags: magento

Magento site home page contains Static blocks(images) and featured products. Some times Static block images disappears and also the featured product section. But that time top menu and footer loads fine. Static block images loads after few minutes without doing anything.I don't have any clue why it happens. Please help me to find out the cause of this issue.

Comment: what have you tried so far? I can think of the following items to check first before checking other possible cause

1. Disable all cache in site->admin
2. Check error logs or reports logs in site/var/reports
3. Check browser console (eg. Firebug inspector)

Comment: I have checked all error logs. But I couldn't find any valuable result.
 Enabling cache will create such issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i ran into this issue before i needed to overwrite the block in question(in my case it was the footer block) and disable caching for that block.

In Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer(app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Footer.php)

```
    protected function _construct()
    {
        //commented out to disable the caching of the footer block 
//        $this->addData(array(
//            'cache_lifetime'=> false,
//            'cache_tags'    => array(Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG, Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG)
//        ));
    }
```

But http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/47197/ seems like a much better solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I noticed that when clicking 'Flush Catalog Images Cache', the home page blocks appears.